# libgdx scene2d buttons stretched

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to make controls for my game, simply four buttons in total, 2 bottom right, 1 bottom left, 1 top right, but the skins are very stretched and act weird. I've tried different skins from the [libgdx skin repository](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins) and they all act different, some are stretched a lot to the right, some are way to big. Here is my code:

```
table = new Table();

boostButtonSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("star-soldier/skin/star-soldier-ui.json"));

boostButton = new ImageButton(boostButtonSkin);


table.setWidth(stage.getCamera().viewportWidth);
table.setHeight(stage.getCamera().viewportHeight);

table.setDebug(true);
table.bottom().left();
table.add(boostButton).width(2).height(2);
stage.addActor(table);
```

Viewport width and height are 40, 24 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you forgot to resize. Your resize method should look like below.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UI widgets in LibGDX are really designed for a ScreenViewport, since UI type stuff is usually ugly if not drawn pixel perfect. But you can get away with using other types of Viewport by setting trilinear filtering on your texture(s), turning off rounding for widgets that support it, and turning off "use integer positions" for any fonts.

But even then, you need to use virtual viewport dimensions that are fairly big (a few hundred units in each dimension). Your units are way too small for a NinePatch to be drawn correctly.

Aside from that, it looks like you are setting the table size based on the camera, but there isn't a guarantee that the camera is sized correctly by the time you are setting up your widgets. Instead of setting its size, call `table.setFillParent(true)` so it will automatically adapt to whatever the size of the viewport is.

Comment: I made my viewport width and height larger, but i dont know which dimensions to choose, because i dont fully understand the impact of the width and height of the viewport, which dimensions should i use if i size them up?

Comment: It depends how sharp you want it to look. Most skins use NinePatches for the backgrounds of widgets. The edge regions of NinePatches are drawn at a size of one pixel to one world unit. So the bigger your viewport dimensions, the sharper your buttons will look.

Comment: Al right thanks, and what does viewport width and height mean? does it mean the size of the world in meters?

Comment: Because i made them a lot bigger and they look good now, but if i set the size to 100,100, they're not square for some reason

Comment: It's explained clearly in the documentation. Sounds like you're using a StretchViewport, which no one should be using. World units are arbitrary. For a UI, the units are pixels of the source textures.